# How to create WIFI hotspot with second Wifi adapter

Tags: windows, wifi, hotspot

I am currently developing an application for machines where we will need two wifi connections. The first one to be connected to a box (hardware data) and the other one for exchanging data between machines.

**We have two wifi modules, the internal wifi card and an external USB wifi module (more powerful).**

**We would like to convert the strong external wifi to a Hotspot.** The problem is, **Windows creates by default the hotspot on the internal wifi adapter**. Then the reception is weaker than if it was created on the external module.

I create the hospot with the following command lines:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

I even tried to disable the internal adapter but Windows still creates the hotspot on the internal adapter.

```
netsh interface set interface name="Internal Network" admin=disabled
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
netsh interface set interface name="Internal Network" admin=enabled
```

I looked up everywhere and nobody seems to have an idea (or they just post back these very command lines without understanding the point).

Does anyone have an idea? Having the weak internal adapter signal is not an option.

Comment: PS: I am a C# developer so if you have "programmatic" suggestions I am open (I am currently working with SimpleWifi but it's limited).

Comment: I want to put a precision:
If I disable the internal wifi, then the hotspot is disabled. If I unplug the USB wifi module, then the hotspot is still there. 
That's how I know the hotspot is created on the internal wifi interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some verification it seems the driver the manufacturer gave me was the wrong version. "netsh wlan show drivers" gave me:

Hosted network supported: No

After communicating with them, they shipped the right driver version.